# Using Con in Raster Calculator of ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-calculator, conditional, evi, con

I have two images, "dvel.img" and "evi.img", and i want to extract water related pixels.

The condition is:

```
(("dvel.img" <= 0.05) & ("evi.img" <= 0.3))
```

I want to get an output by putting condition on both.

How do I write this conditional statement in the Raster Calculator of ArcGIS for Desktop?

Comment: This syntax appears correct for the expression. What error are you receiving? What values did you use for the true and false parameters?

Answer (score 1):

```
Con(("dvel.img" <= 0.05) & ("evi.img" <= 0.3),1,0)
```

The values in the new raster that meet the expression will be set to 1, all others 0. You must specify the name of the new raster in the "Output raster" box.

Answer (score 0):

Just use: `("dvel.img" <= 0.05)&("evi.img" <= 0.3)`

It should work like this. You can make sure avoiding syntax or expression errors by double-clicking the corresponding elements in the raster calculator.

You will get an output raster with the values 0 and 1. For pixels with the value 1, your condition is fulfilled/true.