# Replacing data in raster using condition?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, replace

I have a raster dataset in ArcGIS displaying altitude.

I want to replace all values `< 8` with value `8`.

Other values have to stay the same. How can I do this?

I tried raster calculator, but I don't seem to get the expression right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the raster calculator, you can use the Con() statement(condiotion, value if true, value if false)

```
Con("raster" < 8 , 8, "raster")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Import system modules   
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

# Set environment settings
env.workspace = "C:/project/input/data"

# Execute Con
outCon = Con("altitude" < 8, 8, "altitude")

# Save the outputs 
outCon.save("C:/project/output/output.img")
```

**References:**

- [Tools > Tool reference > Spatial Analyst toolbox > Conditional toolset > Con](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/con-.htm)
- [Using Con in Raster Calculator of ArcGIS for Desktop? [closed]](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170097/using-con-in-raster-calculator-of-arcgis-for-desktop)
- [How to use OR in a CON statement, in the ArcGIS Raster Calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115091/how-to-use-or-in-a-con-statement-in-the-arcgis-raster-calculator?rq=1)